# WebLogic 12c Domain Home Classpath resource throws FileNotFoundException on Windows but not Linux

Tags: spring, classpath, weblogic12c

I'm creating a web application that needs to run on Weblogic 12c. The application is set-up to have an external XML config file, that is provided by the user, read using the Spring ClasspathResource bean (i.e. `<bean id="myResource" value="config.xml>`). On a linux environment, this works fine when the file is placed in the `DOMAIN_HOME`. However, when I attempt the same on a Windows environment, I get a FileNotFoundException as soon as I attempt to access the Resource instance.
The WebLogic installations are from the same jar executable installer and are absolutely identical, so I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work on Windows. I'd appreciate ANY help whatsoever...
Just to clarify, I know I can get around this on Windows by informing the user to set a `CLASSPATH` environment variable but I'd rather not.